# HelloWorld в бэкэнд JavaSpring

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, httpbackend

я создаю бэкэнд. (в Idea) И перед тем как запустить проект, нужно настроить TomCat делаю следующее.

1) Захожу в "Edit Configurations"
2) нажимаю на "+" => TomCat Server => local
3) Deoloyment => "+" (И по идее тут нужно добавить Артефакты) а их нет.

[image: Добавление артефакта]

У меня в проекте есть всего 3 класса

```
public class ApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

private static final String DISPATCHER = "dispatcher";

public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(WebConfig.class);
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet(DISPATCHER, new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
    servlet.addMapping("/");
    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
}
}
```

Контроллер

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/reminder")
public class ReminderController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getReminder() {
    return "may reminder";
}
}
```

Конфигуряция

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.demafayz.spring.app")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

Что нужно сделать, для того, чтобы я смог указать артефакт?

Answer (score 1):

-> Структура проекта -> артефакты -> "+" (если присутствуют сносим) -> "Web App Archive" -> Блок Available Elements (ПКМ  - name_project -> put into output root) -> Если хотитe, поставьте галочку на Build on make